# Is there a continuous function from a 2-sphere into a circle?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Borsuk-Ulam theorem corollary: there is no odd map $f: S^2 \to S^1$.

However, is there any map $f: S^2 \to S^1$?

Comment: How about a constant map?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese yes, any other answer?

Comment: Many. Are you looking for any particular type of map? Your question is incredibly broad at the moment.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese not specific type. I was wondering if there is only one or two such map so if it is not an odd map so I proved the corollary without reference the Borsuk-Ulam theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For example, project the sphere onto a disk bounded by a diameter. Then project the disk onto one of its diameters (a line segment). Then map that interval onto an arc of the circle.

It can even be surjective by making the image wrap around the circle.

But if you want it to be injective, good luck with that.

Comment: $S^2\to D^2 \to I \to S^1$?

Comment: Yes, the intermediate steps are just a suggestion on how to construct the map. In the end, it is a map $S^2\to S^1$.

Answer (score 2):

So, Michael Albanese's answer is probably the best answer (up to homotopy). Since $\pi_2 (S^1) = 0$, every continuous map from $S^2 \to S^1$ is homotopic to a constant map.

Comment: So how can I know the homotopy class is not only contain one element?

Comment: @Brooks: So, computing homotopy groups of spheres in general is a huge open problem. There is a lot of research on the homotopy groups of spheres (in particular, the stable homotopy groups). However, I'm not entirely sure whether there is a criterion to tell you whether a class is 0.

Comment: @Brooks: You might what to check out the wiki-page on homotopy groups of spheres (if you are interested): [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres)

Comment: If you know some covering space theory, every continuous $f :\mathbb S^2 \to \mathbb S^1$ lift to the universal cover of $\mathbb S^1$, which is $\mathbb R$. Then it is clear that any two such maps are homotopic. @Brooks

Comment: we suppose there is another map besides the trivial one, then they are homotopic. but we suppose the existence first, right