# Circle to sphere transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

I have a few questions about transformations:

- What constitutes a linear transformation?
- Is a transformation from circle to sphere a linear transformation?
- If no, why? If yes, what's the formula for transformation?
- Also, is there an example of linear transformation that isn't matrix transformation. Is that true?

Any help regarding this content is greatly appreciated. I'd also love some reference material to clarify my understanding on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One talks of linear transformations for vector spaces. Remember a vector space
comes with two operations: addition of two vectors, and multiplication of a vector by a number (also called scalar).

A linear transformation is function between two such vector spaces for which if those two operations are carried out before applying the function or after applying the function yield the same answer:

Add the vectors and then apply the function: given $u, v$ calculate $u+v$ first and then $T(u+v)$.

Apply function first then add the vectors: given $u,v$ calculate $T(u)$ and $T(v)$ separately  first. Then add those two vectors getting $T(u) + T(v)$.

The final result in the two different  approaches are $T(u+v)$ and $T(u)+T(v)$; these two are the same vectors for a linear transformation.

Similarly given a number $c$ (i.e a scalar) and a vector $v$
first do scalar multiplication then apply function getting
$T(c.v)$ .

Alternatively apply function first and the do scalar multiplication
$ c. T(v)$. These two are equal for a linear transformation: T(c.v)= c.T(v)$

(Mixing decoction with milk and then drinking it I feel I had taken coffee.
Drinking decoction and   milk separately and then allowing it to mix in my stomach I don't get the same effect. So drinking has a non-linear transformational effect on my body!)

Answer (score 0):

A linear transformation from a vector space $V$ to another, $W$.

Is a function $L : V \rightarrow W$ s.t. $L(x+y) = L(x)+L(y),  \forall x,y \in V$.

And $L(c x) = cL(x), \forall x \in V, c \in F$. where $F$ is the base field.

So in essence, is a function that maps straight lines to straight lines.

So the first problem of your question is when you say "transformation from the circle to the sphere". It doesn't make sense to talk about linear transformation unless your domain is a vector space, by "circle" do you mean the curve or the unit disk including its boundary? Either way they do not form a vector space under the usual addition and multiplication.

so I'm going to assume you are talking about the function $f(x,y)= (x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2})$ from $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ being vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$. If so, no, this function is not linear, since $f(2x,0) \neq 2f(x,0)$.

However, the map $g(x,y,z) = (x,y)$ from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ indeed is a linear transformation (called projection). And $g$ does send the sphere to the unit disk.

No, there isn't a linear transformation that isn't a matrix transformation, every linear transformation has an associated matrix representation. This is because how a linear map "look" like is completely determined by where the basis elements are sent to.

Hope that answers your question.

Edit: unit disk not circle

Comment: Your map $g$ sends the unit sphere to the closed unit *disk*.

Comment: ah, thanks for the catch. I'm unsure what map would exist between the sphere and the unit circle, so I'm assuming op is referring to the unit disk when they say "circle".

Comment: i suppose there is indeed a linear transformation that maps the unit circle to the sphere, namely rotation about the x or y axis.

Comment: It is a little unclear whether the OP meant *onto* the sphere, isn't it? But yes good observation. There won't be a continuous map from the sphere onto the circle and since all linear functions between finite dimensional vector spaces are continuous, no such linear map exists.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1705205/is-there-a-continuous-function-from-a-2-sphere-into-a-circle this might be an example of a continuous map from the sphere onto the circle.

Comment: You're right of course! In fact, project the sphere onto the disk and then compose it with any continuous map from the disk to the circle.

Comment: Can we still deduce that no linear maps exists? even if continuous ones exist?

Comment: We can. Any linear map from $R^3$ to $R^2$ must have a nontrivial nullspace and thus there is a point on the unit sphere that maps to $\vec{0}$.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see this, that's slick!